# what is a way to match any char that appears less than a given number of times with regex python?

Tags: python, regex

this is my pseudocode but I dont see that regex has this function, at least the way I am thinking of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys
import os
import re

def main():
    wantedchars = re.match([ANY CHAR THAT APPEARS LESS THAN 8 TIMES], <text will be pasted here>)
    print wantedchars
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to match any ascii char not just alphanumerics and less meaningful symbols.
like I want to match brackets  and backslashes as well if they appear less than 8 times, the only thing I dont care to match/return are whitespace chars.
The reason for this whole thing and why I am not trying to pass the text as an argument is that it is for a one time thing that I will expand on later as part of a learning process I am trying to organize.
I mainly would like to know if I am going about this in the right way.
The other option that came to mind is to iterate over each char in the text and for each iteration increasing a counter for each unique char, then maybe printing the counters with the lowest values.

Comment: 8 times in a row or 8 times overall?

Comment: You will have to count occurrences then, using a `dict` or `Counter`.  gnibbler has working solutions below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 8 chars aren't contiguous, here is a way to do it using Counter (Python2.7+)

```
>>> from collections import Counter

# You can get the letters as a list...
>>> [k for k,v in Counter("<text xx will xx be xx pasted xx here>").items() if v<8]
['a', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'h', 'l', 'p', 's', 'r', 't', 'w', '<', '>']

# ...or a string
>>> "".join(k for k,v in Counter("<text xx will xx be xx pasted xx here>").items() if v<8)
'abedihlpsrtw<>'
```

There's a recipe for doing counters in older versions of Python too. Here's one for 2.5/2.6

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> counter = defaultdict(int)
>>> for c in "<text xx will xx be xx pasted xx here>":
...     counter[c]+=1
... 
>>> "".join(k for k,v in counter.items() if v<8)
'abedihlpsrtw<>'
```

here's one for python2.4

```
>>> counter={}
>>> for c in "<text xx will xx be xx pasted xx here>":
...     counter[c] = counter.get(c,0)+1
... 
>>> "".join(k for k,v in counter.items() if v<8)
'abedihlpsrtw<>'
```

Comment: i am using 2.7, I should have mentioned. the 'k for k,v' i guess the k,v is key, value, but are these just variables you can name anything like other 'for loops' or is this one special because its from Counter?

Comment: @bboyreason, you can name them whatever you like. I just used k,v because this is very similar to iterating a dictionary

Comment: in the first method, this is assuming you know what chars you are looking for? ie, the 'a', 'b', 'd', and so on. What if you dont know what chars, just any that appear, whether contiguous or not, between 1 and 8 times?

Comment: i am getting some ideas from the other solutions actually. I didnt know a for loop could just iterate over a string like that. Do you think I could just alter one of those to work in 2.7, edit: the 'c' would have the value of the index as an int or would it be the char as a string? edit: nm i think i got it

Comment: @bboyreason, the 1st one doesn't need to know the letters. The second line is just there to help show what is going on, you should leave it out in your code